# Can I tell ggpairs to use log scales?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Can I provide a parameter to the `ggpairs` function in the GGally package to use log scales for some, not all, variables?

Comment: Have you tried using the aes() function for this purpose? I see nothing in the help pages that suggests there is any special log capability in ggpairs, but maybe it was assumed you would use typical ggplot conventions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't provide the parameter as such (a reason is that the function creating the scatter plots is predefined without scale, see `ggally_points`), but you can change the scale afterward using `getPlot` and `putPlot`. For instance:

```
custom_scale <- ggpairs(data.frame(x=exp(rnorm(1000)), y=rnorm(1000)),
upper=list(continuous='points'), lower=list(continuous='points'))
subplot <- getPlot(custom_scale, 1, 2) # retrieve the top left chart
subplotNew <- subplot + scale_y_log10() # change the scale to log
subplotNew$type <- 'logcontinuous' # otherwise ggpairs comes back to a fixed scale
subplotNew$subType <- 'logpoints'
custom_scale <- putPlot(custom_fill, subplotNew, 1, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it's good to know how to manipulate the charts. I will try it later; for now, introducing new log'ed variables appears easier.

Answer (score 3):

This is essentially the same answer as Jean-Robert but looks much more simple  (approachable).  I don't know if it is a new feature but it doesn't look like you need to use `getPlot` or `putPlot` anymore.

`custom_scale[1,2]<-custom_scale[1,2] + scale_y_log10() + scale_x_log10()`

Here is a function to apply it across a big matrix. Supply the number of rows in the plot and the name of the plot.

```
scalelog2<-function(x=2,g){  #for below diagonal
 for (i in 2:x){ 
    for (j in 1:(i-1)) { 
      g[i,(j)]<-g[i,(j)] + scale_x_continuous(trans='log2') +
scale_y_continuous(trans='log2')
                        } } 
 for (i in 1:x){  #for the bottom row 
      g[(x+1),i]<-g[(x+1),i] + scale_y_continuous(trans='log2') 
                       } 
 for (i in 1:x){ #for the diagonal
      g[i,i]<-g[i,i]+ scale_x_continuous(trans='log2')  } 
  return(g) }
```

Comment: Just to clarify, this option works as of ggplot2 versoin 2.0.0 and GGally version 1.0.1

Comment: this code does not work for me for values other than 2. and why "g[(x+1),i]", not just "g[x,i]"?!?

Answer (score 3):

It's probably better use a linear scale and log transform variables as appropriate before supplying them to `ggpairs` because this avoids ambiguity in how the correlation coefficients have been computed (before or after log-transform).
This can be easily achieved e.g. like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

log10_vars <- vars(ends_with(".Length"))             # define variables to be transformed

iris %>%                                             # use standard R example dataframe
  mutate_at(log10_vars, log10) %>%                   # log10 transform selected columns
  rename_at(log10_vars, sprintf, fmt="log10 %s") %>% # rename variables accordingly
  GGally::ggpairs(aes(color=Species))
```

[image: example ggpairs plot with log transformed variables]